# how to post facebook status directly to the wall using facebook sdk in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook login button and a share button to update my status, I can login correctly but when I try to share some text as a facebook status on my wall my app crashes with the `nullpointerexception` here is my status update code:

share button click listener:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

and my sessionstate change method looks like this:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");


            bShare.setEnabled(true);

            if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)
                    && shouldAskPermission) {
                shouldAskPermission = false;
                Log.i(TAG, "opened token updated");


                Request.Callback UploadCallback = new Request.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        if (response.getError() != null) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Occured",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                        Object graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                                .getProperty("id");
                        if (graphResponse == null
                                || !(graphResponse instanceof String)
                                || TextUtils.isEmpty((String) graphResponse)) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    "Failed to post Status", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Status Updated",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                };

                Request request = Request
                        .newStatusUpdateRequest(
                                session,
                                StatusDetails.et.getText().toString()
                                        .contentEquals("") ? "status from status plus"
                                        : StatusDetails.et.getText().toString(),
                                UploadCallback);

                request.executeAsync();

            }

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
            // bShare.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bShare.setEnabled(false);

        }

    }
```

but my status get updated when I try using my developer facebook profile, if I try to post using some other facebook profile it gives me null pointer exception in the line:

```
Object graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                                .getProperty("id");
```

I have published the app from the developer console publicly, but I dont understand what to do now? Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can use `publish_actions` for other profiles, you need to go through a review process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Else, it will only work for users with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester).

Comment: Ok I understand, but I made an app 6 months ago with the same procedure and that works till now very well. Why didnt that app need that review?

Comment: because it´s still a v1.0 app. it will need review after april 2015: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog